# Why does meteor get killed in VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, windows-8.1, virtualbox

on Windows 8 I use VirtualBox, where I run Ubuntu with a shared folder to run Meteor.

But after I enter the shared folder and try to run Meteor, it does at first nothing and then just throws "Killed" back. So is there something, that I have to consider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a cross-OS filesystem incompatibility. Make sure the app is running on the virtual disk that is owned by Linux and not the shared folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely the result of a lack of RAM. Meteor is quite RAM hungry.

This also happens on Digitalocean, it depends on the project but I've had issues with just having 512mb RAM. 1GB usually gets rid of the problem.

It does depend a lot of the application & its dependencies though.